# Migrate Magento 1.7 separate store to Magento 2 multistore (just customers and history)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, migration, magento2-migration-tool

We need to migrate the Customers and Orders History from Magento 1.7 to a Multistore Magento 2.

I was using the migration tools and tried to migrate at least the customers:

```
  <steps mode="data">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
  </steps>
```

But I was unsuccessful.

Though, the migration output was successfully:

```
$php bin/magento migrate:data /fullpath/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.7.0.0/config.xml


    [2017-05-22 08:59:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2017-05-22 08:59:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
    [2017-05-22 08:59:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2017-05-22 08:59:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2017-05-22 08:59:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: Migration completed%
```

There is no customer records in admin panel

I have already a couple of days of struggling but I'm keep getting dead ends. Please help me to solve issue.

Maybe it is better to migrate first everything in a Multistore? What do you think?

---

**Update**

Sadly, I didn't receive any feedback to this problem.

So, I decided to take a longer run, not sure if it will get me to the end result though:

1. Configured a Magento 2 multistore websites with all 4 websites + stores.
2. I started to migrate every Magento 1.7 store into a separate Magento
   2 store. That means for all 4 stores of Magento 1.7 I ended up with
   another 4 stores of Magento 2.
3. Then I exported the customers:  `Systems > Export > Customer Main File` to a CSV file, edited the CSV file to reflect the Website Id and store ID I was importing to.

Now, the next point on the Agenda:  **How to migrate the sales Data or at least just the orders history**???!!

If anyone has any any suggestion please give a hand of help - and I'll be for ever grateful :).

Thank you.

Comment: please post all output of migration tool.

Comment: And yes its possible to migrate customer and orders and i had did with magento 1.9 version.

Comment: Did you reindex from command line ?

Comment: Please check after doing reindex in Magento2

Comment: @Jai any help would be very very useful. Regarding the output - I'm afraid that was everything. Before, I have  ignored a couple of fields like store_* so the settings will not be overwritten by migration.

Comment: @KishanPatadia I have reindexed and then I also checked the databases and there are no records being migrated. I'll start from scratch again maybe I messed the configurations.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? or should i post complete answer for this? and fyi ...migration need to start in fresh magento2.

Comment: Hi @Jai, unfortunately the solution I come up with didn't work properly so I would be very grateful to you if you would post your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. First remove " /fullpath/" from 1st line and check. $php bin/magento migrate:data /fullpath/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.7.0.0/config.xml

Comment: also reindex. I am posting complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checklist before starting migration:

- You should start migration in fresh magento 2 with No sample-data. Please make sure to take backup of site and database.
- Create a copy of database (M1 database) which need to mirgate to M2 site. Connect to this database and Both will be on same hosting.
- Make sure you check the connection by test file to both database. This makes sure our migration work better.
- Config.xml file path must be :Root-Site/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.7.0.0/config.xml

**Now we will start migration. I expect you have installed correct version of migration tool.**

To migrate customer and orders history:  We only need to deal with DATA method and data-mode only need below content:

```
 <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
     <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
     <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
     <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
 </step>

<step title="Map Step">
     <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
     <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
     <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
 </step>
 <step title="OrderGrids Step">
     <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
     <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
     <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
 </step>
 <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
     <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
     <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
     <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
 </step>
```

Mapping of map.xml:

```
<map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.7.0.0/map.xml</map_file>
```

Crypt key:

```
<crypt_key>e07mfa00b35f52628ae81d89c4a8cc6db</crypt_key> <!-- ADD your crpted key here from M1 -->
```

Execute below command in root of M2 installation. There should not any change in this command and config file MUST be in this location.

> php bin/magento migrate:data -r --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.7.0.0/config.xml

Clean,flush and reindex from CLI. You will be able to see orders and customers in Admin dashboard.

Map.xml file play important role in migration.If there is any error, post in comment. I will update answer according to your need.

Comment: Thank you @Jai for your answer I'll give a try and update the outcome here.

Do you think is possible to configure the migration process into one store from the multistore website? 
I have: ex1.com and ex2.com and I migrate them to ex.com.
Anyway,I'll try your code and update you, thank you.

Comment: Yes,it possible to migrate process from one store to multiple website. And you may have some issue in process, post here I try to sort out. And if there is any confusion pls also comment. Good luck

Comment: @Jai for migrate one store from multistore we have to add anything to command or need to change it in files. if possible please let me know.

Comment: i haven't tried that but you can migrate all and change the setting in admin. In this way, you will get all data and will remove other store setting from admin. That's fast way, I believe.

Comment: @Jai yes thats good but i am looking for something which is work using migration-tools if i get something. I will inform you.